# Image not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-5, http-status-code-404, laravel-6.2

My application is displaying images perfectly as I am displaying them on the other pages.
I need to apply a watermark on all of those images.
Whenever I try to get the image dynamically to manipulate it gives me the error 404 not found.
However, the link is similar to all other images displaying on the website.
I have tried Image intervention It works fine for the images in public/img folder
but id does not work for the images in the storage/app/products folder.
link:http://usm.gondalgroup.com/refurbished_tetra_pak_machines_supplier_home

working link obtained by inspecting image:http://usm.gondalgroup.com/storage/app/products/pRComIu5U3TkCSppb2PsjxtkcmgpFk4ZGbq4mbRt.jpeg

The link I made using controller and loop: http://usm.gondalgroup.com/storage/app/products/B6ITcW8iA4gyVKbqylw3qweGsqTLMjslIyyvIjes.jpeg

Comment: Please visit my website to check this

Comment: I tried have tried to copy links one by one to make it work by saving images individually but says cannot write to the storage directory. however, its permissions are 755 in my hosting

Comment: You shoould revoke access to your env http://usm.gondalgroup.com/.env

Comment: I will restrict access to .env but does it have to do anything with the problem I am facing?

Comment: Does anyone know why this is happening I have tried to run this on https as well but whenever to get address dynamically in controller I get the message that 404 not found but by inspecting it from view it works fine whenever I edit it or concat  other image name with the base address It gives me an error.

Comment: I have used the command php artisan storage:link

Comment: My files I am trying to access or picture specifically you can stay reside in storage/app/products..

Comment: Obviously I can access and store image in public storage path. But the images I am trying to manipulate are residing storage path